# Maven build uses an HTTP proxy.. that I haven't configured

Tags: maven

I was able to build Maven projects from command line with no issue for as long as I can remember.. But this morning, I am getting some error like it's trying to use the company HTTP proxy to fetch dependencies and it requires authentication. 
We have internal Nexus repositories, so I reallyt don't get why all of a sudden, it tries to go outside.

I checked my M2_HOM/conf/settings.xml, and no proxy is defined there. I checked my env variables, and I don't see anything declaring a proxy either.

Where can it possibly get configured then ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after couple of hours of struggle, I found the problem.

2 weeks back, I needed to install locally a Logstash plugin that wasn't available internally. This required me to fiddle here and there with my config, to allow Logstash to actually go through the proxy and fetch the required dependency - and it involved Maven, as I used the ugly workaround given here : https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2851

As explained in the link, I defined the proxy for logstash plugin in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml .. and forgot to remove it after ;-/

I found this by running the build in debug mode (-X option) and this file was referenced at the beginning.